# Cache Headers on PHP file not working

Tags: php, apache, caching

I have an application where a number of otherwise static javascript files are being generated via PHP to allow configuration options to alter the static files (path like: `mystaticfile.js.php`). Everything works fine EXCEPT that I can't seem to get the cache settings to work and these resources are being reloaded with every page load.

The PHP file uses the following headers to try to set the cache settings:

```
$expires= 60 * 60 * 24 * 60; //cache for 60 days
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=' . $expires);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expires) . ' GMT');
header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
```

However, when the files are served they're showing headers that look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 06 Nov 2016 19:18:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 744
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=95
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
```

My first thought was that it was that it might be because Apache has the `ExpiresActive` flag set on but I don't see any `ExpiresByType` rules set for PHP files.

Reading online it sounds like `ETag` issues could be the problem, but I've added

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
```

to the http.conf file (and restarted the service) and still no dice.

Any thoughts?

Comment: how about making them *.js the browser would likely cache that

Comment: @nogad it shouldn't make any difference. The headers are being set and the browser recognizes them as JS files. The issue is that the browser is receiving instructions not to cache despite the headers being set by php

Comment: Can you try to add some random header (`header('Foo: bar');`), just to first make sure your headers are applied?

Comment: i agree with shouldn't, but that's no certainty, so is something i would personally try.

Comment: @DusanBajic - yeah, the `Content-Type: application/x-javascript` appears to be coming through, so it looks like just the cache headers that are being overwritten

Comment: https://andidittrich.de/2015/09/php-worry-about-some-magical-added-cache-control-header.html

Comment: @DusanBajic - Bam! worked like a charm! Makes a pretty impressive difference on server load and page speed already! Post that up as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: I actually didn't know about this, but `post-check=0, pre-check=0` looked too strange, so I quickly googled that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source: [PHP: Worry about some magical added “Cache-Control” Header ?](https://andidittrich.de/2015/09/php-worry-about-some-magical-added-cache-control-header.html)

> These headers are automatically set by the [PHP Session module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to
>   prevent browser/proxy based caching of your pages. Depending on your
>   environment setup, it’s possible to control these headers by using the
>   [session_cache_limiter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php) function or use the php.ini
>
> To disable these behaviour just pass an empty string to the
>   [session_cache_limiter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php) function as mentioned in the documentation:
>
> ```
> session_cache_limiter('');
> ```